# Best way to say sentence below

Tags: meaning

> Tea is served in a- sugard-added state in this cafe.
>
> Tea is served with sugar added in this cafe.
>
> Tea is served as sugar-added in this cafe.

Which way is better to describe this situation? I wonder if especially first and third sentences correct or not .

Comment: Only the second is natural. Since I do not like sugar in tea, I will not be visiting that cafe.

Comment: Do you mean these are not natural but grammatically correct or these are wrong ?

Comment: They are all understandable, and none are grammatically incorrect. You need to correct the spelling of 'sugard' in the first sentence. The first and last are unnatural and [stilted](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stilted)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all understandable, and none are grammatically incorrect. You need to correct the spelling of 'sugard' in the first sentence. The first and last are unnatural and stilted (Michael Harvey)

A simple way to say this could be

> Tea is served sweet in the cafe.

or, even shorter.

> This cafe serves sweet tea.